# API Gateway failing on all paths with flask

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, api, flask

Hi I have a flask application with the following detail:

```py
application = Flask(__name__, template_folder="template" )
@application.route('/', methods=["POST","GET","PUT"])
def start():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve (application)
```

It is started with the command in an EC2 userdata.sh file as the host is in an EC2 ASG:

```sh
waitress-serve --port=8080 application:application
```

I have a Network load balancer listening on 443 to API gateway. This load balancer talks to the target groups on port 8080 on an EC2. The API gatways sends to the following, where nlb.myhostedzone.cloud is in a private R53 hosted zone:

```
https://nlb.myhostedzone.cloud/:8080
```

I can trace traffic to the waitress server and back, but every single path I try gets:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

I have confirmed that this message is definitely from the waitress server.
The serve is serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080 and the NLB target group is TCP.
I do realise that beanstalk may be better, but for particular reasons, I currently can't use it.
Anyone got any pointers, I'm sure I'm missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to check starting from the place of incident and moving out to universe level. In the question please share how you're tracing the traffic?

Follow the below debugging steps which might give you some clue on the problem:

- The APIs are working locally on the instance itself
- Security group of instance opens up port 8080
- Security group of Load Balancer allows incoming port 443
- The forwarding of traffic from port 443 to 8080
- Test all the HTTP Methods individually (GET, POST, PUT)

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out.  Could not see the wood for the trees, I was calling the integration method with :PORT on the URI. Obviously, flask read the URI as URI:PORT and went what are you talking about. When I modified to URI all came good.